# How to use typescript with a non-typescript js framework?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a Javascript workflow framework.

Steps would be defined like so:

```
var enterSSNStep = function() {
  // some init code
};
$.extend(enterSSNStep.prototype, framework.step.prototype, {
  // declare functions for enterSSNStep here
});
```

Is there a way that I can write the steps in Typescript AND keep the inheritence system I have which I am currently achieving using $.extend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

## framework.d.ts

```
interface IStep {
    new(arg: any): IStep
    doSomething() : any;
}

interface IFramework {
    step : IStep;
}

declare var framework : IFramework;
```

## EnterSSNStep.ts

```
/// <reference path="framework.d.ts"/>

class EnterSSNStep extends framework.step {

    constructor(arg) {
        // some init code
        super(arg);
    }

    public doSomethingElse() {
        this.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: So I just need to define the interfaces in a *.d.ts file and I'm good to go?  That is awesome.

Comment: Yes, if your framework is implemented with good JavaScript code standards you shouldn't have any problems ;)

Answer (score 0):

While you can certainly write code like that in TypeScript you will likely find that doing so will prevent the compiler from doing much type inference or type checking as it won't be able to make any sense of your `$.extend` based prototype hierarchy. Is there any particular reason you need to use `$.extend`? For example the following TypeScript code:

```
class enterSSNStep extends framework.step {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // init code
  }

  // functions for enterSSNStep
  doSomething() {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Gets compiled to the following ES5 code:

```
var enterSSNStep = (function (_super) {
  __extends(enterSSNStep, _super);
  function enterSSNStep() {
    _super.call(this);
    // init code
  }
  // functions for enterSSNStep
  enterSSNStep.prototype.doSomething = function () {
    // do stuff
  };
  return enterSSNStep;
})(framework.step);
```

Note that I omitted the definition of `__extends` above (you can provide your own if you need to do something special, or use the standard one generated by TypeScript).